# How to count syllables

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, syllables

I heard, from a Korean educational radio, “Pay attention ‘**camera**’ is pronounced with two syllables.” I guess it means that the word was pronounced as not /ˈkӕmərə / but /ˈkӕ-m-rə /. Do you not count as a syllable, in this case /m/, when there’s no vowel sound?

Comment: That's right. /m/ is often found closing syllables - think of *ham*, *lamb*, *jam*, *clam*.

Comment: /m/ is the [**coda**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable) of the syllable /kӕm/.  Syllabic [m] rarely occurs outside of the suffix *-ism* or a few other words (such as *chasm* or *blossom*).  The loss of the unstressed syllable in *camera* is called [**syncope**](http://www.pronuncian.com/Lessons/Default.aspx?Lesson=207).

Comment: *camera* may **sometimes** be pronounced "cam-ruh" but that is not the only way it is pronounced.

Comment: @snailplane, Thank you very much. Your link gives me new lights.

Comment: @snailplane This looks like the answer to the question to me! :)

Comment: @WendiKidd Okay, I did my best to turn it into an answer!

Comment: Jim, that's a good point. In my part of the world, it is common to hear *camera* pronounced as cam-e-ra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, /m/ is the [**coda**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable#Coda) of the syllable /kӕm/.

Syllabic [m̩] rarely occurs outside of the suffix *-ism* or a few other words (such as *chasm* or *blossom*).  In this case, we can rule it out because /m/ does not follow a consonant made at the same [**point of articulation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_of_articulation), or indeed a consonant at all; since it can't be syllabic [m̩], we're left with the options of [**onset**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable#Onset) or **coda**; since the vowel following /m/ is [**elided**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision), it cannot be the **onset** of /mə/; therefore the only option left is the **coda** of /kӕm/.

The loss of the unstressed syllable in camera is called [**syncope**](https://pronuncian.com/syllabic-compression).

Answer (score 0):

Snailplane has already explained it quite nicely, but I thought I'd add some information about syllables and syllabic /m/.

Syllabic /m/ can chiefly be found in the suffix *-ism* as snailplane said in their answer. However, it can also be found in many other words in which it's preceded by an obstruent (/z, t, ð/): as in *prism, [bottom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/bottom), rhythm*, respectively.

In present day English, it's increasingly common to [syncopate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/254188/106592) (elide) the vowel in the syllable following the stressed syllable. For instance, *family* used to be pronounced with three syllables; /ˈfæm**ə**li/ (it's still common in some British and American accents, however), but the vowel in the syllable following the stressed syllable has been syncopated by many speakers, so you will hear most speaker pronounce it /ˈfæm.li/.

The same goes for *camera*; it was pronounced /ˈkæm**ə**rə/ (with three syllables), but most speakers have reduced it to just /ˈkæmrə/. There are many other examples such as *comf**o**rtable*, *choc**o**late*, *av**e**rage* etc. [The bold vowel has been syncopated by most—not all—speakers]

Both the pronunciations are perfectly correct.

As for the syllabification of *camera*, there isn't a widely agreed on answer to that! A caveat to readers: what I'm going to say about syllabification is highly controversial and complex.

There are phonological theories, but are much more complicated than you might think. One of the theories is [**Maximum Onset Principle**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272849/106592).

*Camera*, when pronounced with two syllables, can be syllabified as /ˈkæm.rə/: we can't syllabify it as */ˈkæ.mrə/ or */ˈkæmr.ə/.

> /ˈkӕ-m-rə/

This is controversial. Most phonologists think it isn't allowed to end a syllable with short vowels like /ӕ/, so the above syllabification isn't possible.

There's also another theory that suggests that stressed syllables should not have an empty coda, this would mean that /ˈkӕm.rə/ is preferred.

Yet another theory states that lax vowels such as /æ ɛ ʌ ɪ/ cannot have an empty coda (English doesn't have words that end with those vowels), in which case the /m/ is ambisyllabic; it belongs two both the preceding and the following syllable: /ˈkæm.mə.rə/.

---

For syllables and syllabification, the following answers may also be helpful

- https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272711/106592
- https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272849/106592
- https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272796/106592