# How to make syllable structure and sonority graph of "twelfths" and "grudged"?

Tags: spoken-english, phonology, syllables

I have an exam this week and I don't even know how to make syllable structure and sonority graph of the following words: **grudged and twelfths**. I was infected by COVID-19 and have not attended my online classes. .

Are "twelfths" two syllables?

How to make/draw syllable structure and sonority graph of "**twelfths**" and "**grudged**"?

Comment: A question like this belongs to a higher level of English. May I ask if you are a linguistics student? If you are, perhaps Stack Exchange [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/search?q=syllable+structure) is more befitting. Please click on the link

Comment: BTW @student, you should do your homework yourself next time!

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, syllables are a unit of spoken language and have absolutely nothing to do with spelling.

So what is a syllable?

#### Syllable

A syllable is a unit of speech consisting of a vowel, a diphthong or a syllabic consonant with or without preceding or following consonants. The essential part of a syllable is therefore a vowel or a diphthong or a syllabic consonant.

It's not necessary for a syllable to have a vowel, because we have syllabic consonants that make syllables on their own, for instance, the /m/ in the word 'rhythm' is syllabic: [rɪ.**ðm̩**] (syllabic consonants are symbolised by a small vertical line below the syllabic consonant). Also note that vowels can make a syllable on their own but consonants can't.

### Syllable structures

Typically, a syllable consists of three segments which are grouped into two components:

- **Onset:** this refers to the consonant(s) before the nucleus (usually a vowel)
- **Rhyme:** a part of syllable other than the onset. It's further divided into:

  - **Nucleus:** a vowel/diphthong or a syllabic consonant that forms the peak of sonority
  - **Coda:** end of the syllable

So for example the word 'sit' is pronounced /sɪt/, it can be analysed as:

- /s/ → onset
- /ɪt/ → rhyme

  - /ɪ/ → nucleus
  - /t/ → coda

Both twelfths and grudged are monosyllables (one-syllable words).

- twelfths → /twelfθs/: **CCVCCCC**
- grudged → /ɡrʌd͡ʒd/: **CCVCC**

> > > [image: syllable structure of 'twelfths']
> >
> > > [image: syllable structure of 'grudged']

### Sonority

It refers to the relative loudness of one sound compared to other sounds. The sonority of all phonemes of English can be depicted on a sonority scale (sonority hierarchy). A sonority hierarchy is a hierarchical ranking of speech sounds. Typical order of sonority values is:

**Vowels [ɑ, ɔ, ɪ, i] etc > Glides [j, w] > Liquids [ɹ, l] > Nasals [m, n, ŋ] > Fricatives [s, f, θ, ð, z, ʃ] etc > Affricates  [d͡ʒ, t͡ʃ]> Plosives [p, b, t, d, k, g]**

Vowels are the most sonorous whereas plosives are the least sonorous sounds.

So what does 'sonorous' mean?

Singing is a nice way to illustrate this. Try singing the vowel sound [ɑ], it will be quite easy to prolong it. Now try [s]; it's not difficult either, you can prolong it. However, you cannot prolong plosives, try singing [p] or [t].

The importance of Sonority in syllables is reflected in [**Sonority Sequencing Principle (SSP)**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/268464/106592). It states that sounds rise in sonority from onset to the nucleus and fall from the nucleus to the coda of a syllable.

#### Sonority graphs/curves

SSP can be illustrated with sonority graphs/curves:

- /twelfθs/: /t/ is a plosive, /w/ is a glide, /e/ is a vowel (Sonority peak), /l/ is a liquid, /f θ s/ are fricatives (Sonority plateau)

> > [image: sonority curve of 'twelfths']

- /ɡrʌd͡ʒd/: /g/ is a plosive, /r/ liquid, /ʌ/ vowel, /d͡ʒ/ affricate and /d/ plosive.

> > [image: sonority curve of 'grudged']

The vowel is the sonority peak (nucleus). Sonority peaks often correspond to the number of syllables. So there will be two peaks in a word like 'very', hence two syllables.

The reason why some clusters like /pl-/, /kl-/, /sl-/ occur and */lp-/, */lk-/, */ls-/ don't occur can also be explained with SSP. For example, an English word can start with /pl-/ (**pl**ay), but can't start with */lp-/ (***lp**ay). I have explained that in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/268464/106592).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome details and diagrams. If you don't mind am I right about the structure of "sixths": s is onset, i is nucleus, and xths is coda? Thanks again

Comment: @student: Spot on!